# How to refer an Avro schema from Confluent schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, asyncapi

I'm building the documentation of a Kafka message using AsyncAPI. I have an Avro schema on Confluent schema registry (as shown on the following image). The current version is version 9

[image]

I would like to use that schema on my AsyncAPI yaml file.

Assuming that my schema registry has the following information:

```
shema registry url: https://pkdx-rmu1p.eu-central-1.aws.confluent.cloud
key: registryKey
secret: registrySecret
```

Here is the syntax I'm using on my asynApi file

```yaml
channels:
  person:    
    publish: 
      message:
        name: personupload
        schemaFormat: 'application/vnd.apache.avro;version=1.9.0'                    
        payload:
          $ref: 'https://registryKey:registrySecret@pkdx-rmu1p.eu-central-1.aws.confluent.cloud/subjects/person-value/versions/9/schema'
```

But the schema is not getting downloaded. From Visual Studio Code, I have the following error while trying to visualize the asyncApi document.

> Error: Error downloading https://registryKey:registrySecret@https://https://pkdx-rmu1p.eu-central-1.aws.confluent.cloud/subjects/person-value/versions/9/schema Failed to fetch

What is the right syntax to refer an Avro schema from Confluent schema registry in an asyncAPI file?

Comment: Are you able to curl the schema manually with the link?

Comment: Hi @jonaslagoni. Curl is working fine using the command  curl -s -u registryKey:registrySecret GET https://psrc-p6o1m.eu-central-1.aws.confluent.cloud/subjects

Comment: Why do you need $ref twice? Also, you shouldn't put your username and password as plaintext in the spec file, so that's maybe why it shouldn't work this way

Comment: Sorry @jonaslagoni. It an error i made while typing the question here. I just updated removing the duplicated $ref. I'm following the example defined here, but not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't work for you as you have an error in Reference Object

```yaml
$ref: '$ref: 'https://registryKey:registrySecret@https://pkdx-rmu1p.eu-central-1.aws.confluent.cloud/subjects/person-value/versions/9/schema'
```

and additionally you duplicate `https://`. You should provide scheme just once at the beginning of the ref, and after `@` you just go directly with domain name like below:

`$ref` is duplicated.
It should be like:

```yaml
$ref: 'https://registryKey:registrySecret@pkdx-rmu1p.eu-central-1.aws.confluent.cloud/subjects/person-value/versions/9/schema'
```

here you also have another example: https://github.com/asyncapi/avro-schema-parser#usage-with-confluent-schema-registry

Comment: Hi @Lukasz Gornicki. I made an error while writing here. I just updated my question removing the duplicated $ref. The example you mentioned is the same example that i was following. But not working.

Comment: I provided an edit to my answer, I noticed you duplicate `https://` scheme

Comment: Hi @Lukasz Gornicki. Thanks so much for your answers. I finally adopted another solution since It is not good to expose schema registry secrets in the AsyncApi file. Now I have created a separated Avro file and uploaded to the schema registry. The same Avro file is referenced in the AsyncApi file. Thanks a lot